# How do you extract variables as individual arrays after using model.getVars()?

Tags: python, gurobi

This is most likely a Python-specific question, but I am having trouble processing the variables from `gurobi` with Python to be able to plot the outputs.

I have a set of variables that I would like to be able to extract into individual arrays so that I can plot them against a common hourly array.

How does one extract the individual variables in an array format after using `model.getVars()`?

Comment: Can you post how you create the variables p and v?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the variables you are storing them in a list, dictionary or tupledict, you can easily use these objects to access the X attribute (http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/x.html#attr:X) of a specific variable.

So for example:

```
...
myVar = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="myVar")
...
m.optimize()
if m.status == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL:
    print('%s %g' % (myVar.varName, myVar.x))
```

Note that you should check the status of the optimization before querying a solution.

A full example can be found here:
http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/examples/diet_py.html

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I am interested in not just printing it to screen, but storing the results in individual arrays so that I can plot the results using matplotlib. I am trying to find some example code at the moment.

This is the general idea of what I have in mind

a[:,1] = myVar.x[:,1]

However, I know this is not the correct code - but perhaps that explains a little better what I'm after...

Comment: This is the code that I am using -

`model.optimize()
status = model.status
if status == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL:
    sol_p=model.getAttr('x', p)
    sol_v=model.getAttr('x', v)
    print('Optimization status was %d' % status)
    print('The optimal objective is %g' % model.objVal)`

And I was expecting that the sol_p and sol_v variables would be 5 column variables with the correct row length - but it is not - it is returning a tupledict with all of the variable data